# What is Stream API calls in Java

Tags: java

I used for each loop to traverse through an ArrayList consisting an object type. I used intellij. And i get a message on the for each loop which reads

> This inspection reports for each loops which can be replaced with stream api call

What does that mean? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the relevant parts of your code IntelliJ is giving you this advice on.

Comment: It means you could use the classes of the `java.util.stream` package. Not sure it's such a good idea though, depends on your specific code.

Comment: Stream API is a feature introduced in Java 8, it allows you to write lambda expressions so the Intellij is basically telling you that you can use this feature for parsing the array instead of traditional for loop.

Comment: Take a look at [Streams](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/88/streams)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Comment: Using google to ask this would have been quicker.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I did. I couldn't find any. I understood from the answer that i got here. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: @NaveenKarthikeyan You couldn't find any information from the biggest search engine in the world? Are you really sure about that?

Comment: Understand Stream API @ http://www.codeforeach.com/java/java-8-stream-api-and-its-benefits-with-simple-examples

Answer (score 4):

It is called internal iteration one of many cool features of Java 8 here is an example

```
package com.just.stuff;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TestClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> theList = Arrays.asList("A","B","C");

        // The old way
        for (String str:theList ) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }


        // The new way 
        theList.stream().forEach(str->{
            System.out.println(str);
        });
    }
}
```

Here is a nice [link](http://howtodoinjava.com/java-8/java-8-tutorial-internal-vs-external-iteration/)

Comment: "Old way" and "new way" are a bit misleading, since the Stream API is in no way making `foreach` obsolete, especially in simple cases like the example here. Maybe a better example would be a conversion of `"1", "2", "3"` into their integer counterparts.

Comment: I agree, i just wanted to make an explanation as simple as possible .From that point it is programmers responsibility to educate him self that is why i also provide some links

Comment: Thanks brother. It was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Stream API** is a new feature provided by **Java 8** , which allows you to perform operations ( *filter, map, sort, reduce* etc ) on **Collections** such as list, queue etc in sequential or parallel ways and in simpler ways.

Have a look at below article which explains its use with a short example :

[Java 8 - Stream API  - short examples](http://www.codeforeach.com/java/java-8-stream-api-and-its-benefits-with-simple-examples)

Comment: Can you share good document again? as link provided by you is no longer in existence